# Adding a Second IP Address to an Existing Network Adapter

Tags: network

On linux boxes it is possible to add multiple ip addresses to the same network interface.

It's achived with the following command:

```
ip addr add 128.133.123.83/24 dev eth0
```

Is there any way to to the same with OS X ?

I've tried to put multiple ip addresses (comma separated like the dns) in System Preferences / Network with no luck...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty easy. Open System Preferences, go to Networking, then click the Plus sign under the left bar. Choose the interface, give a name to the adapter configuration you're creating, then press OK. You will have to provide manual configuration of IP address and DNS for the second entry -- DHCP won't work for it, because it shares the same MAC address as the original entry, so the router won't issue it another address. Click Apply when you're done, and enjoy. Your adapter now has two IP addresses.

Comment: How can it make it work with a browser? I mean, I can ping or telnet using the new address, but I can't connect using the browser...

Comment: You can reorder adapters in order of preference by dragging and dropping them.

Comment: OK, it works both for Ethernet and WiFi, thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this on Ventura?
My adapter setting is still working, but I am not able to adjust the IP address anymore, as the interface has changed completely.

Comment: @Simon, it seems to me this is accessible through Network preferences, selecting your interface, then clicking the Details button.

Comment: @zneak, unfortunately that does not work. The details of the second entry are the same as the original entry. If you set a static IP for the second entry, your original is also changed.

Answer (score 29):

`sudo ifconfig en0 alias 128.133.123.83/24 up`

and to remove...

`sudo ifconfig en0 -alias 128.133.123.83`

Comment: Does this stay between reboots? or does this need to be re-applied each boot?

Comment: @deweydb it does not stay between reboots.

Comment: if the second address is in the same subnet, it seems to need to be added as /32. See the man page for ifconfig and look for 'alias'. at least on monterey.

Answer (score 2):

.. and to remove the alias added in brabic's answer

`sudo ifconfig en0 -alias 128.133.123.83`

Comment: This would make a nice edit to the other answer.

Comment: yes - but i didn't have enough reputation to comment on the other answer :-(. working on it..

Comment: Click edit and make the changes - your content belongs in the body of the answer, not as a comment or a half answer

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and worked for me. Since I have two Wi-Fi networks, one from work and another from home hot spot using my iPhone.

Go to network settings, add a service, then set interface to Wi-Fi and new name (three dot right down).

While your Wi-Fi is disconnected assign IP address to second Wi-Fi you have recently created.