# Adding a second IP address to an existing network adapter on Ventura

Tags: network, wifi

Up to Mac OS 12 it has been possible to add a second IP address to a network interface.

See here: [Adding a Second IP Address to an Existing Network Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/910/adding-a-second-ip-address-to-an-existing-network-adapter/911)

Since Ventura, the UI has totally changed. The second IP address I added is still there, but I am no longer able to change the address or add a new one.

Is there any way via UI or terminal to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the solutions in your linked article is still valid for Ventura.

`sudo ifconfig en0 alias 128.133.123.83/24 up` will still give you an aliased IP on the adapter in question `en0`, and as long as your selected ip and CIDR block are in the correct range, all should work well.

`sudo ifconfig en0 -alias 128.133.123.83/24` will remove the alias.

<strike>I was unable to figure out how this is done in the UI - sadly this seems to have been removed. :(</strike>

**UPDATE:**   I found the aliased network interfaces in Ventura[image]

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. The option using ifconfig is good as workaround but is unfortunately not permanent, the setting is lost after a reboot.

Using "Add Service" allows to add a second interface for my WiFi, but when I edit the details of that new interface to add a static ip address, my primary WiFi interface is changed, too.

Comment: @Simon If adding a second IP with `ifconfig en0 alias` works but is lost on reboot, can't you add a LaunchAgent which runs once after reboot to set it again?