# How to add IP alias in MacOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, network, alias

Seems like Apple decided to remove features, in previous MacOS versions it was very simple to have multiple IP addresses for the same interface, now no more.

The duplicate service no longer work

Anyone who know how to do it?

A simple explanation of how to add multiple IP addresses to a network interface in MacOS Sonoma

Answer (score 0):

This solution is only for an Ethernet interface, there is no solution for Wi-fi.

Fundamentally, nothing has really changed since this Q&A [Adding a Second IP Address to an Existing Network Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/910/adding-a-second-ip-address-to-an-existing-network-adapter). The details are different.

In System Settings, select Network and then Add Service... under the details drop down.

[image: Add Service...]

Choose the existing interface and a new service name.

[image: Service name]

Now select the new service, click the Details... button enter the IP address, DNS, etc. that you want. These will be manual settings because DHCP can't work twice with one MAC address. You should get something like:

[image]

You should be good to go!

Comment: This really does not work for WiFi interface, if you add more than one all will have the same settings, I'm speaking with Apple support about this issue they recognized the bug but don't have a solution yet

Comment: Terminal commands shown for Ventura no longer works for Sonoma, it seems they changed the system deeply and added bugs

Comment: @FabioFrumento I will amend my answer following your comments.